# Why using percentage for font size isn't doing what it should?

Tags: html, css

I have navigation items inside boxes.. like this

```
 <a href="#" class="box">
 <h2>Portfolio</h2>
 </a>
```

css:

```
 a {
 display: block;
 }
 .box {
 background: #ff6b6b;
 width: 25%;
 height: 250px;
 }
```

what I want is the text inside the box to occupy 80% of the parent box.

I tried...

```
 .box h2 {
 font-size: 80%;
 }
```

But this doesn't achieve the result I'm trying to get. it makes the text super small instead of taking 80% of the parent element..
why is that? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried 0.8 em?

Comment: It is making it 80% of the default browser font-size.

Comment: try something like ``font-size:0.8em``

Comment: A font-size of 80% is the same thing as .8em.  There's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A percentage can mean different things depending on where it is. For example, `padding-top:100%` actually makes the top padding equal to the element's *width* - not something you'd guess, but extremely useful for aspect ratios.

In this case, a font size percentage is relative to the parent element's font size. Here, your element will have a font size equal to 80% of the parent's font size.

Comment: I see, so what should I do in this case?
I tried..
.box {
font-size: 100%;
}
.box h2 {
font-size: 100%;
}

but this doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 1):

LIke this please use `em` i think its properly working.

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwRh8/)**

**css**

```
 a {
 display: block;
 }
 .box {
 background: #ff6b6b;
 width: 25%;
 height: 250px;
 }
.box h2 {
 font-size:2.5em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
```

---

for your reference **[link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)** or **[link1](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/C12.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like,

```
.box h2 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Font-size % property: Sets the font-size to a percent of  the parent element's font size

From reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp